# How Can i create Windows Machine on AWS with 1 GB EBS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Windows default EBS size is 30 GB. We can take snapshot and create another volume but that is to increase size. Moreover my intention is to keep only one partition with 1 GB volume.

Any tricks here ?

Comment: You can pick the volume size when you create the instance. 30GB is the default but you can change that to whatever you want before creating the instance. Are you doing this via the API or command line and having trouble figuring out how to specify the EBS size or something?

Comment: @MarkB That won't work. `Volume of size 8GB is smaller than snapshot 'snap-0914f93833779ce04', expect size >= 30GB` Without creating your own AMI, you have to stick with the minimum default.

Comment: both using CloudFormation or AWS console.. issue is minimum size requirement of EBS for windows server is 30 GB.. I am wondering how can i keep it to 1 GB... i attach the new 1 GB volume and copy from C: to D (new volume). Now wondering how can i change the root drive to C: rather than D

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't pay attention to the desired size, I thought you wanted a larger size, not smaller. As mentioned, you can't make it smaller than the default. Also, you get lower IOPS performance with smaller EBS volumes, so you may want to reconsider going with such a small volume size.

Comment: Why do you want only a 1GB disk? Are you just trying to save money? You will need to create your own disk image, which means you'd have to patch and maintain it. Much easier to use the standard disk images supplied by AWS. At 10c/GB/month, there's not much benefit. (And even Microsoft recommends 32GB for Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there are no real tricks there.

I once tried reducing the Linux root partition size, however that VM wouldn't start up because the disk was too small and couldn't copy the snapshot to your disk.

You could check if Windows Nano suits your needs and this one comes with 8 GB.

The other option would be building your own image/AMI. However, looking at the [Windows Server 2012/2016 system requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/essentials/get-started/system-requirements) they say you need a `60-GB system-partition`. So 30 GB is already quite small and I'm sure you are unable to install any modern full Windows on a 1 GB drive. This isn't Windows 95 anymore...

Comment: ok let me put that way.. is there any way by powershell or so i can reduce the size of root volume !